# git - what is the best practice for team work on a feature branch?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

We have the following branches:
`master` and `develop`.
We created a new branch `feature` off of `develop` and assigned a team to work on it.
During development:

- remote `develop` accepts new commits by other teams.
- remote `feature` accepts new commits pushed by the team members working on it.

Sometimes there are hot fixes pushed to `develop` that need to be updated in `feature` as well.
Of course, at the end of the cycle, `feature` should be merged into `develop`.

We don't have a single workflow to keeping `feature` and it's local copies in sync with `develop`, and then making sure all local copies are based on the same commit.

My suggested workflow is as follows:

**Keeping up-to-date with `develop`**

1. New commits are pushed to `develop`
2. I rebase the `feature` branch:

   ```
   git checkout feature
   git pull --rebase origin develop
   git push origin feature
   ```
3. All local `feature` copies run: `git pull --rebase origin feature`

**Updating the `feature` branch from local copies**

1. A team member has finished his work on the `feature` branch
2. He makes sure his local copy is up to date:  `git pull --rebase origin feature`
3. He merges his commits into `feature`:

   ```
   git checkout feature
   git pull origin feature
   git merge local-feature
   git push origin feature
   ```

**Merging the `feature` branch into `develop`**

1. I make sure feature is up to date with `develop`:

   ```
   git checkout feature
   git pull --rebase origin develop
   ```
2. I merge into `develop`:

   ```
   git checkout develop
   git pull origin develop
   git merge feature
   git push origin develop
   ```

We do all that `pull --rebase` stuff in order to keep linear flow and make sure all our changes are merged using fast-forward.
However, as you can tell, there are a lot of commands to run every time.

**Is this really necessary? Are we doing it the "right" way?**
Would you suggest another flow?

Comment: You can design/implement your own git commands (or git alliasses).

Comment: Check out https://sandofsky.com/blog/git-workflow.html

Comment: I'd say that `git merge local-feature` is redundant - if you do a rebase of the local copy on top of remote 'feature' branch - this already takes care of merging your changes.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you follow this model: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

[image]

I think most of the demonstrated commands are correct, you can however make things easier by implementing [git alliasses](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases)